# Predict Titanic Survival

Tags: machine-learning

I am working on Predict Titanic Survival project in Codacademy, I am trying to update the column of the CSV file change the 'Sex' column form male/female to 0/1 but got an error. Someone could please help!

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 13, in <module>
    passengers['Sex']=passengers(['Sex']).map({'female': 1, 'male': 0})
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable`

Code:

```
import codecademylib3_seaborn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Load the passenger data
passengers = pd.read_csv('passengers.csv')
print (passengers)
# Update sex column to numerical
passengers['Sex']=passengers(['Sex']).map({'female': 1, 'male': 0})
print (passengers.head(1))
```

Help please!

Comment: Hi there! You have an abundant parenthesis after passengers, ```passengers(['Sex'])```. If you remove them this should work fine. You have a ```TypeError```, because Python thinks that you are trying to pass the array ```['Sex']``` into a function, whereas passengers is a ```DataFrame```.

Answer (score 0):

As @Uzay Macar mentioned in the comment that if you removed the parenthesis it would work fine but here is good method to get that done.

```
train["Sex"][train["Sex"] == "male"] = 0
train["Sex"][train["Sex"] == "female"] = 1
```

Or

```
data.loc[data["Sex"] == "male", "Sex"] = 0
data.loc[data["Sex"] == "female", "Sex"] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try encoding from sklearn too

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide more details of your suggestion?